# ThreadpoolExecutor , Waiting for other running thread to complete when one of the running thread throws exception

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

**Problem statement** : I am using **ThreadPoolExecutor** in loop to call a window process (Abby)for textual file processing.At a time there are 5 threads running which calls the window process. But in some cases one or more of the running thread throws exception.
In such cases I want to allow other running threads to complete their task and threads which has thrown exception is gracefully handled after completion of running threads. **How can I do that?**
So far I came to know that we can use **ThreadExecutionCompletionService** and **cancel** other running threads once exception occurs 
but my scenario is different -I want other running threads to complete

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
final ExecutorCompletionService<String> completionService = 
            new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(executorService);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    completionService.submit(new Task());
}
```

Comment: "gracefully handled" means "to continue their execution" or what?

Comment: I added some code below that's worked for me in the past the solves the issue you're having.  You'll have to adjust it to fit what you're looking for, but it should give you the basics of what you need to do

Comment: Thanks for the code sample , however I have limitations I have to find solution in java 7 and not java 8. "gracefully" means - I want all the other threads that are in running state and have not thrown exception to complete successfully before I exiting from the main thread or handling the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about (**Notice you'll have to tweak this for your own usage**):

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                     () -> {
                         // do work here and return
                         return work
                      },executorService)
                      .exceptionally(e -> {
                           logger.error("Error here"+e);
                           return null;
                       })
      );
}
CompletableFutre.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).join();
```

Comment: I have found an alternative using counters and AtomicBoolean variable to solve my problem